# Error: Node Sass version 8.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-sass

When I start a React app with npm start, I got this error.How I fixed this error?

```
./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5
-3!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/App.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 8.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
```

[Here is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggB4P.png)

Comment: have you tried to update all your packages ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't use node-sass anymore

The module `node-sass` is now deprecated and replaced with a more robust new version which is `sass`. Only change the module and all would work fine. You can uninstall the old one and install the new one:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

And all Works same !

#### For those who want to use `node-sass` anyways

To avoid the error, you can use the following table to install the appropriate version `node-sass` for your installed Node.js version which you can check by the command `node --version`.

```
npm install node-sass@(your version)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. `npm uninstall node-sass`
2. `npm install sass`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error in one of my angular projects and I did try `npm uninstall node-sass` and `npm install sass` but it was giving the same error.

So, this process below worked for me (in Windows)

1. Go to **C:\Users\FakeUser**
2. Find **node_modules** folder and **delete** it
3. Also delete the **node_modules** folder present in your project directory
4. Now do **npm install** in project directory to generate fresh **node_modules**